# Django - DateTimeField in DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

How can I display DateTimeField year in urls which is using DetailView ?

Here is my code:

models.py

```
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

views.py

```
class UpdatesDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'Upadtes/detail.html'
    model = Post
```

urls.py

```
url(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', UpdatesDetail.as_view(), name='updates-detail'),
```

Now my url looks like that: `127.0.0.1/this-is-just-test`, but I want my url to look like this `127.0.0.1/2017/09/17/this-is-just-test`. How can I do it ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: The DetailView inherits from SingleObjectMixin. I recommend that you read the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin Even if this doesn't solve your problem directly, it will help you with it.

Comment: Why do you want to have the date in the url? Will you use the date to identify the article? Or is the article identified uniquely by the slug field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments for `year`, `month` and `day` also along with `slug`

```
url(r'(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', AktualnosciDetail.as_view(), name='aktualnosci-detail'),
```

**In html**

```
<a href="{% url 'aktualnosci-detail' year=post.publish.year month=post.publish.month day=post.publish.day slug=post.slug %}"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how can I use it in `href`? Here is my html `<a href="{% url 'aktualnosci-detail' slug=post.slug %}"`

Comment: I am updating answer for that. Hold on.

Comment: @xaos_xv, I have updated my answer, Have a look now? And let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: Thanks it's working almost perfect, but month is `9` not `09` and same with day.

Comment: But you can manipulate with that na, if you are fetching views out of that the you can compare as `(publish__month=month)` and there should not be any problem.

Comment: @xaos_xv, If it helps you can select and upvote my answer. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: I don't understand. What should I do now ? Where should I use `(publish__month=month)` ?

Comment: I meant if you want to fetch something out of model you can do using the month or year you get from url

Comment: @xaos_xv, If the solution worked for you. Please vote up and select the answer else if any problem let me know via comments below. Thanks for all the cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

I found great example in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups). Pozdrawiam :)